# Is it possible to mutate the content of a local notification in swift?

Tags: swift, push-notification, notifications, uilocalnotification

In the next version of my app, I want to integrate the possibility that the user can enable weekly reports like the screentime feature from apple.

I know how to setup Local Notifications (The code is already working for other types of notifications like reminders for events), but for this idea, I need the notification text to be updated shortly before firing because I don`t know the exact content of the notification when I add it to the NotificationCenter.

Is there a function which is called shortly before firing or how would I do this?

This is my working code for scheduling notifications:

```
fileprivate func generateNotification(title: String, body: String, triggerDate: DateComponents) -> String{
   //Trigger
   let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)

   //Content
   let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
   content.title = title
   content.body = body
   content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

   //Request
   let identifier = UUID().uuidString
   let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

   let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
   notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
       if let error = error {
           print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
       }
   }

   return identifier
}
```

Comment: store the indentifier and just create the request again when you have more accurate details, it will replace the previously scheduled one

Comment: Yes, that was also my idea, but I only know the correct details when firing. So how do I set up a background task which is called only seconds before the notification fires? (The application will be connected to an account and so events can be removed on other devices so I have no possibility to update the notification)

Comment: Do you really need to change it seconds before it fires? can't you just keep updating the notificaiton as you get more information through the week?

Comment: Otherwise, you can put your code in `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter` UNNotificationCentreDelegate: willPresent method, although the docs say that only fires in the foreground. there are other delegate methods that may be useful